# Almost sure convergence on integral of Poisson process

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, poisson-process, almost-everywhere, borel-cantelli-lemmas

Let $N_t$ be a Poisson process with intensity $\lambda$.
Then how to show that
$$
  \lim_{t\rightarrow 1} (1-t) \int_0^t \frac{2}{(1-s)^2}dN_s = 0
$$
almost surely?

**What I have done.**

Since for some $\varepsilon>0$, the probability $\mathbb{P}\left\{ N_{1-\varepsilon,1}=\infty \right\}$ or $\mathbb{P}\{dN_1 > 0\}$ is zero, so my intuition says that the above equality should hold.
First, I tried to apply [Borel-Cantelli Lemma](https://www.google.com/search?q=borel+cantelli+lemma&oq=borel+cantelli+lemma&aqs=chrome..69i57j0j0i395l5j0i30i395l3.7835j1j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8):
$$
  \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \mathbb{P}(E_n)<\infty \implies \mathbb{P}(\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} E_n) = 0.
$$
So I define $E_n = \left\{(1-t_n) \int_0^{t_n} \frac{2}{(1-s)^2} dN_s > \varepsilon \right\}$ for some $\epsilon>0$ and $t_n \rightarrow 1$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$, and using Markov's inequality:
$$
 \mathbb{P}(E_n) \le \frac{\mathbb{E}\left[(1-t_n)\int_0^{t_n}\frac{2}{(1-s)^2}dV_s\right]}{\varepsilon} \\
= \frac{1-t_n}{\varepsilon}\int_0^{t_n}\frac{2}{(1-s)^2}\lambda ds \\
= \frac{2}{\varepsilon}-2\frac{1-t_n}{\varepsilon}
$$
is not tight enough to bound the sum $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \mathbb{P}(E_n)$.
This is same for the higher moment bounds.
Then is it possible to show the above equality?

Thanks.

Comment: Hint: Let $ A_n=\{P_{1-1/n}=P_{1+1/n}\} $, then $A_n\subset\{\lim\limits_{t\to0}(1-t)\int_0^t\frac{2}{(1-s)^2}dN_s=0\} $

Answer (score 1):

As you observe, $N$ has no jump at time $1$, a.s. Let $T\in[0,1)$ be the last jump of $N$ before time $1$. ($T=0$ means there are no such jumps.) Then because, $s\mapsto(1-s)^{-2}$ is increasing,
$$
\int_0^t{2\over (1-s)^2}dN_s\le 2N(t)\cdot(1-T)^{-2}\le 2N(1)\cdot (1-T)^{-2}.
$$